# Why did Tiny untie Mary and let her go?

Tags: house-of-1000-corpses

In House of 1000 Corpses, there is a scene where Mary is dressed in a doll dress and has her face painted up. She is tied to Tiny's bed. When Tiny comes in, she says, "Please let me go" and Tiny reaches over and unties her. Why does he do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question, there is no clear answer provided during the movie, but there are some hints as to why he might have done it.

- The most compelling answer I could come up with is that Tiny just has a soft spot for women. At dinner, the mother says

  > My baby boy gets shy around new people, but he'll warm up to you, *especially the girls.*
- I re-watched the scene and noticed as she is trying to leave the room, Otis catches her and puts her in a cage. He then turns around to look at Tiny as if to say "what happened?" and Tiny shrugs his shoulders as if to say "I don't know." So, maybe Tiny didn't know why he did it. Then again, he could have just been lying to protect himself.
- As I recall, the family seems to like messing with people's heads, as well as killing them. So, it's possible that Tiny knew she had no hope of escape and just wanted to mess with her.
- Tiny is obviously mentally challenged and just seems to follow the orders of the family. As I recall, Mary was the only one to tell Tiny do something other than the family, so it's possible he simply follows any order (or request) that he's given.
- During dinner, Tiny's mother says that his father set the house on fire and Tiny was badly burned by it. It's possible that Tiny resents the family and wanted to let her go as a small way to get back at them.

Comment: I believe that your 2nd to last answer is going to be more accurate. His lack of mental maturity gives him a type of "innocence" that would lead me to believe that he is just doing what he is told. I don't think he is lying to protect himself and is actions in both movies clearly shows his love for his family.